# How to export multiple animations for a game character? (specifically, Unity)

Tags: animation, unity, unreal-engine

Title says it all. I use Unity, so I really need a solution that works for that, and so do many others. Although, people also want to know how it's done for UE4, source, cry-engine etc, so answers that take them into account as well, would be better.

Comment: Best workflow is a nonsense and does not exist. The best one is tailored to your needs and depends on the project, people working on the project and software that is involved. If you want this answered you will have to narrow it down a lot. *Regarding your profile: if you have more than junior level experience you can write you have senior level.*

Comment: Your question is subjective and therefore can only be answered subjectively. Maybe a discussion-based forum like [Blender Artists](http://blenderartists.org/forum/) would be a better place to ask this kind of question. That said, I suggest studying everything about Blender's Multires, Sculpt Mode, and Normal Baking features. Cycles Baking is also a way to add realism, so of course this means learning Cycles. Learn to rig and animate. Rigging will vary from software to software, so you may need to bake your animations.

Comment: ...I've narrowed it down to a more simple question. 

"Regarding your profile: if you have more than junior level experience you can write you have senior level." - Unrelated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOTE: for ue4
what i do is i put every animation in its own action and then set the anim player equal to whatever the keyframing is for that specific anim. i then export it as fbx using selected only and unchecking nla strips.

Comment: This was the kind of answer i was after, and this would most likely work for my purpose. Someone might feel want to feel free to edit my question to match the answer because I don't know how i could have worded it differently to match the format of this site, but i think it's useful to other users.